# How to get Pug template to send the variable value to email application instead of variable name?

Tags: html, pug

How can I write 'mailto' in a Pug template in a way that the user automatically gets the real email value in his default email application when he clicks on the email? Writing it in this way:

```
a(href=`mailto:#{user_email}`) Send an email
```

gets the string `#{user_email}` in the email field, instead of the variable value.

Comment: Can you escape the `#` with an backslash?

Comment: @Spingolini It isn't the special symbol that matters: Attribute interpolation was dropped in Pug v2. The correct way to solve this is proposed in the answer of the OP, through string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

I found it! Within a link I should have directly read from the source, like this:

```
a(href=`mailto:`+ user.email) Send an email
```

Answer (score 1):

Three years ago this answer was valid but I think is deprecated.
Not working for me.

You can find more in this answer => [Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51869179/12259105)

Here's the kicker :

```
const from = 'helloworld@dev.com'

a(href=`mailto:${from}`, target='_blank', ...) Answer to #{from}
```

You can see the use of backticks plus the dollar sign.

Simple Template literals => [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)