# pug variable not evaluated on a href tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

In my Express JS web app, a `login` route renders some variables to the login pug view.

In `login.js`

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  var locations = ["Location 1", "Location 2"];
  var count = 0;
  var title = 'Login';
  console.log("req.originalUrl=" + req.originalUrl);

  res.render('login', {
           title: title, // Give a title to our page
           jsonData: locations, // Pass data to the View
           count: locations.length,
           originalUrl: req.originalUrl
      });
});
```

In `login.pug`

```
extends layout

block content
  div(class='container mt-3')
    h2 Welcome to #{title}, #{count}, #{originalUrl}
    a(class="btn btn-primary" href="/location/new" role="button") NEW
    br
    br
    ul#locList(class='list-group')
      for location in jsonData
        li(class="list-group-item")
          a(href='#{originalUrl}' + '?' + location, class='list-group-item list-group-item-action')
            h2=location
```

The `originalUrl` variable in the `a href` was not evaluated as '`http://localhost:3000/login?Location%201`', but '`http://localhost:3000/login#{originalUrl}?Location%201`' instead.

Then I had to change it to '`a(href=originalUrl + '?' + location, class='list-group-item list-group-item-action')`' in order to make it work.

In a nutshell, `a(href='#{originalUrl}')` does not work while `a(href=originalUrl)` works, for `a href`.

However, the same variable was correctly evaluated at line '`h2 Welcome to #{title}, #{count}, #{originalUrl}`' as '`Welcome to Login, 2, /login`'.

How was the same variable evaluated differently on `a href` from `h2`?

Comment: It's because when you are using `#{variableName}` inside quotes, pug is evaluating that as a literal string. But when you are trying to use it outside any quotes, then it understands that this is a variable and uses its value instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is known behavior that came about a few versions ago (I think 2016). This `#{style}` interpolation is not supported in attributes:

> Caution
>
> Previous versions of Pug/Jade supported an interpolation syntax such
>   as:
>
> a(href="/#{url}") Link This syntax is no longer supported.
>   Alternatives are found below. (Check our migration guide for more
>   information on other incompatibilities between Pug v2 and previous
>   versions.)

For more see: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

You should be able to use regular [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
a(href=`${originalUrl}`)
```

Comment: Add an enclosing parentheses on the link and it will work e.g. a(href=`${originalUrl}`)

Comment: @Mark Meyer, THANK YOU, I have been searching for an answer for the longest time. I tried all sorts of syntactical tricks but none worked...yours did.!

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do that, write directly the variable, without using quotes, brackets, $, !, or #, like this:

```
a(href=originalUrl) !{originalURL}
```

The result of this is a link with the text in originalURL

Example:
if originalUrl = 'www.google.es'

```
a(href='www.google.es') www.google.es
```

finally you get the link: [www.google.es](http://www.google.es)